# Setting-up Tags on azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

i am trying to set Azure tags on _private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link objects.  i use following code .

**variable.tf**

```
  variable "private_dns_zone_record_tags" {
  type        = map(string)
  default     = {}
  description = "Tags for private dns zone related resources."
  nullable    = false
}
```

**main.tf**

```
data "azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link" "public_endpoint" {
  for_each = local.private_endpoints

  name                  = var.private_dns_zones_for_public_endpoint[each.value].virtual_network_link_name
  private_dns_zone_name = var.private_dns_zones_for_public_endpoint[each.value].name
  resource_group_name   = var.private_dns_zones_for_public_endpoint[each.value].resource_group_name
  tags                = var.private_dns_zone_record_tags
}
```

i am getting following error

```
│ Error: Value for unconfigurable attribute
│
│   with module.this.data.azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link.public_endpoint,
│   on ../../private_endpoint.tf line 50, in data "azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link" "public_endpoint":
│   50:   tags                = var.private_dns_zone_record_tags
│
│ Can't configure a value for "tags": its value will be decided automatically based on the result of
│ applying this configuration.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link"`
  https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link.html

VS

- `data "azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link"`
  https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link

In the resource the tags is an optional argument
But in the data the tags is an attribute not an argument

You can not do what you are doing in the data, use the resource instead.

---

A good read from the official documentation:

- https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/data-sources
- https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/resources

Comment: these private dns zone will be created within the private endpoint creation, If we can't add them manually, can we let tags inherits from private endpoint resource?

Comment: @shameera2008 What do you mean by `we can't add them manually` ... You can create those with resource instead of data sources, What is stopping you?